# Removing the TOC entry from the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

Using the `article` document class I have transferred a DOC template to a tex format (I am using miktex).

The template specifies a given section appearing prior to the table of contents i.e.:

```
\section{Mandatory section}
bla bla bla

\tableofcontents

\section{Other section}
```

Problem is that, once generated, the PDF document shows the table of content entry in the table of content i.e:

```
Mandatory section ....... 1
Content  ................ 2
Other section ........... 3
```

I want to remove the Content entry from the TOC, but havent found any method to do so.

Any help is high valued.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. The `article` document class doesn't add a ToC entry to ToC by default.

Answer (score 3):

The template seems to incorrectly use \section instead of \section* for the table of contents. A little let magic should help here:

```
\let\mysection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\mysection*{#1}}
\tableofcontents
\let\section\mysection
```

If you can, fix the template.